# how do i replace certain words in a sentence with php

Tags: php

Suppose I have this sentence: "The president obama came back to america from africa with his family".

How do I replace "obama" with "bush"?

Comment: You read the documentation on str_replace() (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and then try using the function in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) functions:

```
$sentence = "The president obama came back to america from africa with his family";
$changed = str_replace("obama", "bush", $sentence);
```

Answer (score 1):

That was a silly question. If you just googled it, would've found the solution:

> str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )

```
$subj  = "The president obama came back to america from africa with his family";
$search = "bush";
$replace   = "obama";

echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subj);
```

Comment: The question was __NOT SILLY__. The only problem with the question I see is OP did not tried anything.

Comment: Thanks. But the fault was mine. I just threw out a question without trying anything. It won't happen again. I'll try my best in future. :)